Minimizing the Distance Between Rotated Coordinate Frames with Axis Constraints
I am trying to find the optimal rotations for two coordinate frames, $F_1,F_2\in SO(3)$​, to make them as close as possible to each other, subject to the constraint that each frame can only rotate around a specific axis.
Let $R_1(\theta_1)\in SO(3)$​ represent an axis-angle rotation around fixed axes $v_1$​ by angle $\theta_1$. Similarly define $R_2(\theta_2)\in SO(3)$ to rotate around fixed axis $v_2$ by angle $\theta_2$.
The objective is
$$
\min_{\theta_1, \theta_2} \| R_1(\theta_1) F_1 - R_2(\theta_2) F_2 \|^2
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\max_{\theta_1, \theta_2} \space \operatorname{tr}(R_1^T(\theta_1)R_2(\theta_2)F_2F_1^T)
$$
The rotations can be rewritten using Rodrigues' rotation formula as $R=I+\sin(\theta)K+(1-\cos(\theta))K^2$. After substituting with the formula, expanding, evaluating the trace, and rewriting coefficients as $a_i$, the result is
$$
\max_{\theta_1, \theta_2} a_1 \sin(\theta_1) + a_2 \sin(\theta_2) + a_3 \cos(\theta_1) + a_4 \cos(\theta_2) + a_5 \sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\\ + a_6 \cos(\theta_1) \sin(\theta_2) + a_7 \sin(\theta_1) \cos(\theta_2) + a_8 \cos(\theta_1) \cos(\theta_2)
$$
I do not know how to proceed. Is there a better way to approach this problem? Does this optimization problem have a closed-form solution? If not what would be a good way to approach minimizing the objective? Would gradient descent work well here?

Could you explain more?

I do not understand. $R_1$ rotates around $ v_1$. $R_2$ rotates around $v_2$.

@user619894 A rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has three degrees of freedom. We cannot expect to reach every rotation. In general, a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ degrees of freedom. It is even quite simple to create examples in which $R_1F_1=R_2F_2$ cannot be achieved.

@ReinhardMeier you are right, dont know how I missed that. deleting comments
